# What would cause an exception to occur at "TaskModel.Interop.Task.SaveTaskState" and how can I debug it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

For one of my Windows Phone 8 apps, I can see a high crash count with the following details:

**Error**

> State saving failed. This is most likely due to insufficient State
>   buffer capacity. App requires [3289135] bytes which likely exceeds
>   NavServer limit

**Stack trace**

> at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.SaveTaskState()    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnPause(UInt32 reason);

Obviously these are internal functions, but I don't know why they're occurring. I can find very little information online for this exception, except that saving and restoring state seems to come up. I am following the approach at this guide on MSDN for doing this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967548(v=vs.105).aspx

There is also a similar question on MSDN forums which doesn't have a solid answer:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/74934801-8713-42be-9216-825cd0c09851/strange-0x87b20c05-exception?forum=wpdevelop

Question: Is there any obvious reason why this exception would occur or any way I could attempt to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this was fairly obvious in the end, given the error message:

> App requires [3289135] bytes which likely exceeds NavServer limit

Basically I had a `List` loaded from `IsolatedStorage` which contained a large amount of data and when the app was de-activated or started running in the background, the data on my view model is saved to `State`.

I solved it by marking this `List` with the attribute `[IgnoreDataMember]` so my large `List` will not be saved to `State`. I simply re-load the`List` for display in the `OnNavigatedTo` event. Basically, make sure there is not a large amount of data in your view model. In my case, it was just over 3MB of data which was causing this error to appear.